# Inconsistency between vampires age and their power

Tags: plot-explanation, true-blood

Throughout the show, it's being said numerous times that the older a vampire is, the stronger they get. And especially Godric, who is said to be the strongest vampire that exists.

However, Godric himself says:

> It won't take long, at my age

Referring to how long it will take the sun to burn him. This contradicts the fact about being stronger, as it would be expected a strong vampire will take longer to be destroyed.

How can this inconsistency be explained, if at all?

Comment: "This contradicts the fact about being stronger, as it would be expected a strong vampire will take longer to be destroyed." That is your conjecture. I don't think this is stated anywhere in the show.

Comment: @BCdotWEB just common sense, that something stronger is harder to destroy.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I would say it is part of definition that stronger things are harder to destroy which takes longer.

Comment: I would say this is simply an inconsistency or an (odd) constellation of rules one must not question as suggested by CGCampbell.

Comment: I think that it's more that generally, the older the Vampire is the stronger they physically are/abilities are, but the sun is the catch 22. It's not inconsistency, it's in-universe mythology-building. Every good story has foils so that no one person, creed, or species holds all the power, all of the time. It's how you humanize and have a dramatic story worth telling, by pointing out limitations.

Comment: @DarthLocke yes that is pretty much what the accepted answer says. Still wonder if there are references, that will make the question on topic.

Comment: You could try an "analysis" tag and edit to explain that you are interested in the show 's mythos as a possible explanation. There use to be a mythology tag, but I think it no longer exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known fact about vampires in the author's world.

It was never explained, in detail, in either the books upon which the series is based, or the series itself.

As vampires age, among other things, they grow more supernaturally stronger, physically. Yet they are also affected by UV radiation to a larger extent. It's one of the (many) rules of that universe and is not explained.

I would say it's not an inconsistency, but rather is treated as a consistent rule. The older a vampire is, the quicker the UV radiation burns them and they die. Throughout the written novels, this is true, as it is in the television series. It is a rule and is consistent in it's application.

An inconsistency would be if a young vampire burned quickly or an older one didn't. Then that would need an explanation.

Comment: If I understand it right you are saying that the plot is consistent in regard to the rules. But I think the OP means that the rules themselves contradict each other.

Comment: @Igor is correct however since you say that's known fact in that world I accept it, I didn't read the books and don't remember the whole TV series, I'm re-watching after several years.

Comment: @IgorstandswithUkraine Yep, that is exactly what I'm saying. This isn't [worldbuilding.se] where we need come up with the science behind why something works. Or to figure out a ret-con to an inconsistency from an author/director post-first-movie (looking at you Lucas, again and again and again, or even Roddenberry) Within the True Blood Universe, that is the way things are and the author (and showrunner/writers) were consistent _with this particular rule_. (at least as far as I can recall)

Answer (score -4):

The more you stay as a Vampire, the longer you are dead. This is why sun effects less fresh Vampires and more old Vampires.

Comment: Sorry but this does not make much sense.

Comment: No it is totally logical.

Comment: To you, maybe. If you can find reference to support your claim you are welcome to add it to your answer.